# Where can I find the folder which I downloaded from gcloud bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

By using gcloud shell I have downloaded all my bucket but I couldn't find the downloaded files.

I used the command

```
gsutil -m cp -R gs://bucket/* .
```

Comment: The last dot ( `.` ) in the command you shared indicates that you want to copy the content to your current location. So as @GAEfan suggested, you you should be looking for the files in the directory where you ran it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the command gsutil cp, as documented here:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp

The parameters for this command are:

```
gsutil cp [OPTION]... src_url dst_url
```

So you used Option gsutil -m for to perform a parallel (multi-threaded/multi-processing) copy.

Then you also added -R to traverse all directories in your bucket

As "destination URL" you entered a "." which specified the current working directory.

So your files should be located in your home directory, or in any directory where you switched to using the cd command inside your command window.

Answer (score 0):

It would download to the directory you were in when you ran the command.  If you never changed the directory using  `$cd ...` command, then it should be at the root.  On a Mac, that would be `Macintosh > Users > YourName`.